# Holding down a button will loop an action until it is release

Tags: java, android, libgdx

First of all, i'm trying to make a puzzle game with the same concept as this game,

LINK: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-b2LunJPXC0 (the title of the game is Siren Fantasia)

Where in the user will hold a single piece of item from the gameboard and the objects that is surrounding it will be rotated clockwise until the user releases it.

I want to imitate that, When the user holds the button, the action will continuously loop until the user releases it.

Heres a sample of the code that i have already made:

```
float delay = 2f;

button.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            if(pointer == 0) {
                Timer.schedule(new Task(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        int counter = 0;

                        do{
                            Timer.schedule(new Task() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    button2.setVisible(false);
                                }

                            }, delay);

                            Timer.schedule(new Task() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    button2.setVisible(true);
                                }

                            }, delay);

                         }while( counter >= 1 );

                    }
                }, buttonDelay);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

And the output ain't the one that i wanted it to be. When i hold button, the button2 doesn't set to visible(false) and visible(true). But when i kept holding it over and over again, it would sometimes work.

I really need help.
Thank you.

Comment: When is `counter` being increased? You have `while counter >=1` but you initiate it with `counter=0` and it doesn't increment at all. Also, I have an idea, instead of doing 2 tasks, why don't you check inside the task if the button is visible, then make it invisible, and vice versa.

Comment: Oh yeah, i forgot a bout that, thanks! Now, I currently change the loop to a while(true) so it would be infinite. Is there a way to use a infinite loop without freezing the program?